# Sudden Runtime error '9' on a two year old macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm having issues with a macro that I've been using for months with little issue. The macro is designed to reformat an excel report and insert it into a different workbook within excel. Today, I keep encountering this message:

```
runtime error '9': subscript out of range
```

When I select Debug, it highlights this line of code:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

I am not a coder. I've used the macro button to copy what I do to shorten tasks, but outside copy and pasting the errors and highlighted code into a search engine to see what someone else may have tried, I'm not savvy enough to troubleshoot the logic. The code has always worked, I've done nothing different, but today it's throwing that '9' error. What I have tried is renaming the worksheet to match the code, so basically "Sheet1". I have copied the previous month's worksheet, deleted the old data, and tried running the macro. I even tweaked the code as was suggested by a google find with an individual suffering a similar problem, but I just created a '1004' error because I don't totally understand the logic with xlTop vs. xlDown other than the implied direction. That didn't work so I'm back to square one.

Here is my macro code in total. It's simple enough.

```
    Sub UserStats()
    '
    ' UserStats Macro
    '
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Doesn't show the macro 
        run on the screen, speeds up program
    '
   Cells.Select
   With Selection
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
   End With
   Columns("A:A").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   Columns("B:C").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   Columns("C:D").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   Columns("D:I").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
   Rows("1:7").Select
   Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   Columns("A:D").Select

     ' SortUserStats Macro
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
          SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
          xlSortTextAsNumbers
      With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
          .SetRange Range("A:D")
          .Header = xlNo
          .MatchCase = False
          .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
          .SortMethod = xlPinYin
          .Apply
End With

  ' CopyUserStats Macro
    Cells.Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 12
    Range("A2:D2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Workbooks("User Stats Prep.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Activate
    Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1, 1).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Cells.Select
    Selection.RowHeight = 12
    Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1, 1).Select

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

End Sub
```

I appreciate any suggestions, otherwise I'll be adding the new data row by row copy and paste style.

Comment: Do you have a sheet called "Sheet1" still? It would probably work again if you replaced that line with `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Sort.SortFields.Clear` but you have to be careful if you change this that the first sheet is the one you really want to clear

Comment: Also, if this macro is stored in the workbook for which it's used (i.e. not in `PERSONAL` or other additional workbook), you could try changing `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: I do have a sheet called "Sheet1" . When I created a new sheet as opposed to copy/moving last months sheet and deleting data in an attempt to get the macro to work. I added your suggestion and it threw a     Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error. When I ran the debugger, this is the code that was highlighted: Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1, 1).Select

Comment: If there is only one used/non-empty cell in column A (i.e. `A1`) of first worksheet in `User Stats Prep.xlsx`, then the error may be that you are trying to select the row after the last row on the sheet (i.e. a non-existent/ out of bounds row). You could try getting rid of the `+1` on that line temporarily as an investigative step.

Comment: chillin, it sort of works when I remove the +1. Sometimes it runs as it should, and sometimes it tosses out that runtime error '9'.

Comment: If you add an @ to a username they'll got a notification - @chillin

Comment: Honestly I think this would be easier to just start from scratch if you could just tell us what you want it to do. It seems like essentially you want to just sort some data on your activesheet and then copy that over onto "user stats prep" if you could just show us pictures of mock data and where you want it to be put this'd be pretty simple to complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to re-write it so that it doesn't have the excess that the macro recorder generally creates. If this does not work or if it works differently than before, please describe exactly what is wrong/the error

```
Sub UserStats()
    '
    ' UserStats Macro
    '

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'hides screen, speeds up program

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

        'format all sheet1 cells
        With .Cells
            .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
            .RowHeight = 12
        End With

        'delete A:D, D:I, and 1:7
        .Columns("A:D").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("D:I").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Rows("1:7").Delete Shift:=xlUp

        'Sort UserStats
        With .Columns("A:D").Sort

            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add _
                key:=Range("A1"), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                Order:=xlAscending, _
                DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers

            .SetRange Range("A:D")
            .Header = xlNo
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply

        End With

        'Copy UserStats
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(Range("A2:D2"), Range("A2:D2").End(xlDown)).copy
    End With

    With Workbooks("User Stats Prep.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
        .Cells.RowHeight = 12
        .Cells(Range("A1").End(xlDown).row + 1, 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End With

    Workbooks("User Stats Prep.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=True

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you! This solved the problem and program runs as it's supposed to now. I don't understand why it stopped initially. I had been speaking to the firm that helps retrieve the data for my reports, but they hadn't changed anything or added anything to the report to get the macro to freak out like that. I thank you for your help!

Comment: @BetO Glad it helped! Please consider clicking the checkbox to accept it as the best answer :)